# How to Count Distinct Users, Get MaxDate of the USER and the UserId of the latest record

Tags: mysql

I want to get the latest date a record has been created (CreatedDate), the UserId and the total number of Unique users in the the table.

This is what I have so far and does not seem to work.

```
Select UserId, MAX(CreatedDate), Count(Distinct UserID) AS 'Number of Users'
From DPP_Exports__Customers
```

Can anybody help?

Thank you,

Iqbal

Comment: Everything in one select?

Comment: Yes I need the query to be in a single select statement, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for UserId of latest record:

```
select userid,CreatedDate 
from DPP_Exports__Customers  
order by CreatedDate  desc limit 1;
```

query for max date of each user:

```
select userid,max(CreatedDate)
from DPP_Exports__Customers  
group by userid;
```

query for distinct user count:

```
select count(distinct userid) from DPP_Exports__Customers
```

single query for all:

```
select  cust.userid,max(cust.CreatedDate) as max_createdDate,
        (select count(distinct userid) from DPP_Exports__Customers) as distinct_user_count,
        (select userid from DPP_Exports__Customers order by CreatedDate  desc limit 1) as  latest_userid
from DPP_Exports__Customers  cust
group by cust.userid;
```

Comment: Yes I need the query to be in a Single Select Statement, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it...

Select GROUP_CONCAT(UserId), MAX(CreatedDate), Count(Distinct UserID)AS 'Number of Users',Max(UserId) as latest_user From DPP_Exports__Customers
```

Comment: This concatenates all the UserId's is there anyway to show the latest UserId   only along with the date associated MaxDate and the total Number of unique UserId's, many thanks.